# Where does Google get my website's summary from?

Tags: google-search

If you google 'verpress.com', you get the following website summary...

> Free hosting service web, Hotel, Dvd movie, Download free slot,
>   Accommodation cheap, Bet online, Adsl connection, Pres, Mms, Press,
>   Account bank, Mobile ...

This text isn't in the page source so where does it come from?

Comment: You can adjust that text by adding a META Description inside your HEAD tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: How long have you had the domain? And how long has your site been up on the domain? I am voting to migrate to [webmasters.se], where it is hopefully a better fit.

Comment: Its been up for a few weeks or so.

Answer (score 1):

Google has ([currently](https://www.google.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://verpress.com/)) indexed an older page which was available at http://verpress.com/ for a long time (at least since [2011-02-02](http://web.archive.org/web/20110202085146/http://verpress.com/) and at least until [2013-08-06](http://web.archive.org/web/20130806193627/http://verpress.com/)).

Looks like a domain parking page, which probably had shown ads related to the terms you still see in Google’s snippet.

When the current page gets crawled by Google, the description in the snippet will change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Google can pull descriptions from a number of places off of your website (Yahoo Directory and DMOZ, for example), there are some tags you can add to ask google not to use them, but it's not 100%. You should install a reputable SEO plugin like WordPress SEO by Yoast and set a meta description to whatever text you like.